# Regex to find a string from a matching pattern

Tags: regex

How can I find out a string only if it is preceded and followed by specific set of strings?

For example,

```
<input id="amount" type="hidden" value="105">
<input id="orderId" type="hidden" value="10000">
<input id="userId" type="hidden" value="200">
```

I want to find out ***10000*** from the above string. Basically I want to write an expression to find out the value between the below two conditions

- starting with `<input` followed by `orderId`, which is followed by `value="`
- ends with `">`

.

Comment: [**Do not use regex to parse HTML!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Answer (score 1):

```
Regexp: /<input.*orderId.*value="(.*)"/g
```

Detailed @ 
https://regex101.com/r/oFuGw4/1

You would not want to use regexp to do this in Javascript.

Just do this

```
<script>
var value = document.getElementById("orderId").value;
</script>
```

Comment: Gonna use it in JavaScript

Comment: I am not allowed to enter JS code in the tool, but only regex.